# Tkinter is acting odd

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to code a `game` in python using `tkinter` library. The controls are `w, a, s, d`. I don't know why but the key bindings are not running functions. I removed `event` parameter from the functions and ran them, they did not work.

The character did not move. I checked the function which is used by functions for moving (`w(),a(),s(),d()`) which is `update` function(`update` function never works).

For checking each function I removed `root.mainloop()` and executed functions, I found out that `Joe.place_forget()` works randomly, when i restart IDLE then it will either work or not work, it's random. However, as mentioned earlier, `update` function never works. Why is this happening?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

root=Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.title('Zombie Surge')


frame=Frame(root,width=root.winfo_screenwidth(),height=root.winfo_screenheight(),bg='#23961d')
frame.pack()


entities={'character':{'Joe':PhotoImage(file='Joe.PNG'),'zombie':PhotoImage(file='zombie.PNG')},'hand':{'empty':PhotoImage(file='empty.PNG'),'knife':PhotoImage(file='knife.PNG'),'gun':PhotoImage(file='gun.PNG')},'drop':{'bullet':PhotoImage(file='bullet_drop.PNG'),'knife':PhotoImage(file='knife_drop.PNG')}}        

current=Label(frame,image=entities['hand']['empty'],bg='#23961d')
Joe=Label(frame,image=entities['character']['Joe'],bg='#23961d')
Joe.place(x=635,y=322)

#script for movement of Joe
def coord(entity=Joe):
    return entity.winfo_x(),entity.winfo_y()

def update(x,y):
    Joe.place_forget()
    Joe.place(x=x,y=y)

def replace(file,nfile):
    x,y=coord()
    file.place_forget()
    nfile.place(x=x,y=y)

def w(event):
    x,y=coord()
    update(x,y+10)

def a(event):
    x,y=coord()
    update(x-10,y)

def s(event):
    x,y=coord()
    update(x,y-10)

def d(event):
    x,y=coord()
    update(x+10,y)

#binding the GUI to functions
frame.bind('<KeyPress - w>',w)
frame.bind('<KeyPress - a>',a)
frame.bind('<KeyPress - s>',s)
frame.bind('<KeyPress - d>',d)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because `frame` does not take the focus.  Call `frame.focus_set()` before `root.mainloop()`.  Or bind the events on `root` instead of `frame`.

Comment: thankyou so much @acw1668! I was having a hard time and u made it ez, just put this in an answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `frame` does not take the focus.

You can either:

- call `frame.focus_set()` before `root.mainloop()`; or
- bind those events on `root` instead of `frame`